# C++ file in Swift/Objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

i am currently developing a simple app on my own.

I want to use a library from some sample app. The library consists of .mm files (C++ code) and runs perfectly on the original project.

However, when i copy the library to my file (Objective C), it seems that my other object files do not see the file. All the classes and protocol defined in this library are not recognised at all.

Errors are such as "No type or protocol name", "Unknown typename "classname" " when i try to use the library classes and protocols.

I have spent quite a lot time searching, but to no veil.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you import the headers?

Comment: Yes, i have imported all the headers, trying to include UIKit, @import Foundation at every possible place to make it work as well. But can't seem to make it work at all.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161946/best-way-to-bring-c-into-objective-c-project) on programmers SE.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C simply won't understand the C++ language constructs like `class`, etc.  If you want to use this Objective-C++ code in your app then your app also needs to become Objective-C++ which can be done simply by renaming all your source files from `*.m` to `*.mm`.

In the case of Swift, however, you cannot expose C++ to it at all, and can only integrate it with C or Objective-C, so you are therefore forced to create a pure Objective-C wrapper for the C++ code (i.e. implementation in `.mm` but exposing no C++ types in its header file).

Comment: Yep. Objective-C++ (the mutant child of C++ and Objective-C) is the way to go. It's quite nice to hide all you C++ code using an Objective-C wrapper thereby keeping you App nice and Apply.

Comment: The problem is that the original project which has only that particular library being coded in C++ work perfectly fine without any errors.